# How do I use autoarchive to decrease primari .pst filesize?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, archiving

I have a computer which has Windows and Office installed on an 60 GiB SSD. Size of mailbox is around 13 GiB. The .pst file associated with the mailbox is around 31 GiB and I need to somehow make it smaller.

After setting autoarchive and trying to force archive using mailbox cleanup options, the archive.pst (on another drive) has now 13 GiB worth of mails, but I set only mails older than 12 months to be archived. It appears that all mails, even those outside the time range, were sent to archive.

Another thing I've noticed is that the archived mails are still in the main local mailbox. How do I move them so that they are only in the archive? Do I need to manually delete them from the main mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new data file with it's location outside the SSD. Head over to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Other` -> `Auto Archive`.

Under Auto Archive - Change the timeframe for 'Clean out items older than x months`and under`Move old items to...` select the data file specifically created above for archives

[image: auto archive settings]

Comment: I already have done all that before asking the question. Do I need to enable the `Delete expired items` option too? I need to have mail archived in the archive and can't delete them from there, but emptying main mailbox is fine.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - I don't think that's necessary. I don't have access to Outlook for the weekend ( use it at work) - will check it out on Monday and update